# Android: Curtain up and down animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two Layouts, first is some custom layout, and the second is a ListView

The first one is default, and when I need to open up a ListView, I just pull up the bottom of the first layout, so it goes up like a curtain in theaters and shows me my ListView

When I click some ListItem, curtains close and hide the ListView

Here I made a quick picture of what I meant:
[curtain animation http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32772116/curtain.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32772116/curtain.png)

I have two layout files: default.xml and list.xml

So I need an advice on how to implement this curtain-like animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from API demos. There are two xmls named `push_up_in.xml` and `push_up_out.xml` in `res/anim` folder. Also, you can refer `Views->Layout Animations->Grid Fade` or `Views->Layout Animations->Reverse Order` for the same kinda animation. Best luck!

Comment: I found in my samples folder, but I can't find it in the API Demos application itself

Comment: Yes. In API demos, they have not given any reference to those animations it seems. But they are there, and I've used it to achieve same kinda animation. Create a new project with "Create project from existing samples" and find API demos there. Please let me know, if you can't get it work.

Comment: I found it, but I don't know how to implement it. If you've achieved same kind of animation, could you give me the source of it's implementation, thanks

Comment: C'mon man. Get sporty. You have the source code of whole API demos. Dig it out. Create a new android project and while creating, select the option "Create from existing samples" and find API demos. And check my updated answer. If you find it helpful, mark it as accepted.

Comment: I just don't know how to use xml animations

Comment: I found them, but I don't know how to use this two xml files to my two layouts and create a single activity

Comment: To put these animations in two different activities, you can use `overridePendingAnimation(anim1, anim2)` method. But to use it in a single activity put your efforts.